# Docker change wordpress to HTTPS from HTTP

Tags: wordpress, docker, networking, centos, port

I struggle to change configuration of already set-up container to use SSL.

I have VPS with CentOs 8, on which I have 2 containers running, one with Wordpress and other with wordpress DB. Wordpress works fine on port 80. I'd like to enable SSL and move it to 443.

Right now what I did:

1. Open firewall port 443 for docker trusted interface;
2. Changed wp-config.php with wp-home and wp-site url to use respectively https protocols;
3. Added FORCE_SSL_ADMIN in wp-config.php
4. In stoped container changed hostconfig.json and config.v2.json to use respectively 443 protocols to 80

EDIT 1

Current outcome:
When running curl localhost:443 I got wordpress page returned (from local machine to wordpress), however I do not think it uses https protocol.

Desired outcome:
I'd like to be able to serve wordpress over https for external traffic. Right now I got connection refused message.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I wouldn't bother doing anymore config at container level, rather I'd use an application server like Nginx or Apache to resolve DNS and redirect incoming traffic to the containers via reverse proxy.

If this is not possible, could you please provide the (I'm assuming) docker-compose file and dockerfiles you have to set up your server?

EDIT:
Don't run the docker container on 443, it can listen internally on any port you want, but map it to something else, like 8080, for the following example config.

nginx.conf

```
http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;

  server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.key;
      
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did not use docker-compose. I simply used docker run commands to setup my containers from correct images.

Comment: I am fine with using Nginx, however as I am able to publish nginx web service over 443 and 80 ports (https and http) respectively, my container remaines unaccessible from external networks :(

Comment: I suggest using docker compose simply because it's simple to setup and it can auto-restart in case of a power outage, for example. So you install nginx, setup reverse proxy for your containers, and complete the config to enable ssl termination, certification management, and http to https redirection. Everything I mentioned above can be found in some simple google searches. I can provide the exact config you need to do but right now I'm writing from my phone, let me know.

Comment: Hi Gabriel I have nginx natively running on CentOS machine, if you could support with the config it would be great. I do not have docker compose installed because it simply was not required to run an app. I think I might add it at some point but I'd like to keep number of applications installed on this machine to minimum. So right now I have localhost running on 443, which unknowingly I cannot access from outside. Should I change it to other port and expose Nginx with 443 and 80 to 443 redirection?

Comment: Thanks! That worked and I can access WP site right now. However there is small issue with the links. Once clicking on the link it redirects me to localhost so let's say I land on my website - {{my-ip}}, the link exposed is showing {{my-ip}}/my_contact_page, however once I click on it I am redirected to 127.0.0.1/my_contact_page. I think it might be related to this 'rewrite' part? I already upvoted your answer :).

Comment: Also it seems like port 80 is causing too many redirects. I'm looking into Nginx configuration right now maybe I will be able to fix it.

Comment: Update, ok I figured it out. Those redirects were related to wordpress, once I changed URL to use http one everything worked. So I almost have a working copy of wordpress. However it seems like I right now have mixed content issue as not all content is served over https and I do not have any styles available for my application.  I need to figure out how to serve CSS with https urls for wordpress.

Comment: Update 2. And I finally figured out how to fix admin-panel and styles. Basically in wp-config I removed if before $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'; Now it works.